# Mockito's ArgumentCaptor: One method name, two method definitions

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to write a test that verifies the calls of the same method name that can accept two different parameters.  The code snippet I tried originally:

```
ArgumentCaptor<Label> labelCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Label.class);
Mockito.verify(fakeSheet, Mockito.times(4)).addCell(labelCaptor.capture());

ArgumentCaptor<Number> numberCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Number.class);
Mockito.verify(fakeSheet, Mockito.times(2)).addCell(numberCaptor.capture());
```

However, Mockito complains that addCell was run 6 times on the first verify.  So, I tried this:

```
ArgumentCaptor<Label> labelCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Label.class);
Mockito.verify(fakeSheet, Mockito.times(6)).addCell(labelCaptor.capture());

ArgumentCaptor<Number> numberCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Number.class);
Mockito.verify(fakeSheet, Mockito.times(6)).addCell(numberCaptor.capture());
```

Which runs, but gives me all 6 argument calls in both ArgumentCaptors, storing the information of all 6 objects I am expecting into both ArgumentCaptor instances.

This feels so very wrong- sure, I could write a test with it, but the fact that my captor isn't distinguishing between the two classes feels dirty.  Is there a way to get Mockito to distinguish between the two?

Comment: Does it work with `Mockito.verify(fakeSheet, Mockito.times(4)).addCell(Matchers.any(Label.class));` and `Mockito.verify(fakeSheet, Mockito.times(4)).addCell(Matchers.any(Number.class));`? Are `Label` and `Number` in the same inheritance tree?

Comment: Ahh, I tried this and it revealed my misunderstanding of the library.  The two types do share the parent, but for some reason I thought when I was digging I saw specific method signatures for each type, but it turns out this isn't true.  That would explain my problem, thanks!

Comment: So just do `Mockito.verify(fakeSheet, Mockito.times(6)).addCell(commonCaptor.capture());` and then check if `commonCaptor.getAllValues()` list contains 4 Labels and 2 Numbers.

Comment: between the two verify methods just reset the mocks and it should work as it is.

Comment: Note that `any` doesn't do type checks (as it stands for **anything**) and neither `ArgumentCaptor` does , the class arg is here to avoid casting. This mentionned in the javadoc.