# Mockito's ArgumentCaptor: One method name, two method definitions (Part 2)

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I asked a [similar question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279617/mockitos-argumentcaptor-one-method-name-two-method-definitions) in which I'm using a single method name, but have two different arguments I'm passing along.  This one does not involve argument types that share a parent class.

I am using PowerMockito to return a PrintWrite from a constructor.  I need to mock its print methods.

There are four kinds of print/println calls I am tracking:

```
print(long l)
print(java.lang.String s) 
print(char c)
println()
```

Particularly what I care about is the one that prints a long.  I have the following setup:

```
Mockito.doNothing().when(fakePrintWriter).println();
Mockito.doNothing().when(fakePrintWriter).print(any(Long.class));
Mockito.doNothing().when(fakePrintWriter).print(any(String.class));
Mockito.doNothing().when(fakePrintWriter).print(any(Character.class));
```

With the following verifies, which I want to capture certain arguments with:

```
Mockito.verify(fakePrintWriter, Mockito.times(11)).print(outputCaptor.capture());
Mockito.verify(fakePrintWriter, Mockito.times(1)).print(longPrintCaptor.capture());
Mockito.verify(fakePrintWriter, Mockito.times(9)).print(eq(','));
Mockito.verify(fakePrintWriter, Mockito.times(3)).println();
```

Which slaps me in the face with this:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
printWriter.print(<Capturing argument>);
```

Drilling down by testing a print on a long normally, I discovered that calling print(long l) is actually calling println.  So, I instead changed my long print setup/verify to this:

```
Mockito.doNothing().when(fakePrintWriter).println(any(Long.class));
...
Mockito.verify(fakePrintWriter, Mockito.times(1)).println(longPrintCaptor.capture());
```

Which then gives me the resulting conflict with println:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
printWriter.println(<Capturing argument>);
...
Actual invocation has different arguments:
printWriter.println();
...

Expected :printWriter.println(<Capturing argument>);
Actual   :printWriter.println();
```

Like yesterday I am at a loss as to how to resolve this- I considered using a custom Answer to track the string that gets outputted (I want to verify the actual order of the values that are being outputted) but I believe doing so would only result in similar errors.  Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: I have sidestepped the issue by returning a temporary file from the constructor instead, and then analyzing the file's text.  It's much simpler anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to mock the PrintWriter, simply use a real one, that writes to memory, instead of to a File.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintWriter fakePrintWriter = new PrintWriter(byteArrayOutputStream);

// invoke method on unit under test

assertThat(bytes.toString()).isEqualTo(expectedOutput);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the `ByteArrayOutputStream` approach and it seems to be empty when I run `bytes.toString()`. I've found the following seems to work if you don't mind allowing implementations in your test:

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
...
assertThat(printWriter.getBuffer().toString()).isEqualTo(expectedOutput);
```